# for loop in a bash script

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I am completely new to bash script. I am trying to do something really basic before using it for my actual requirement. I have written a simple code, which should print `test code` as many times as the number of files in the folder.

**My code:**

```
for variable in `ls test_folder`; do
    echo test code
done
```

"test_folder" is a folder which exist in the same directory where the bash.sh file lies.

**PROBLEM:** If the number of files are one then, it prints single time but if the number of files are more than 1 then, it prints a different count. For example, if there are 2 files in "test_folder" then, `test code` gets printed 3 times.

Comment: Does one of your two files have a space in the name? Does one of the files have a `*` or other glob character in the name? See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for why this approach is a problem.

Comment: yes, one of my file had a space in its name. I think that was the reason of problem. Sorry, I tried to search a lot but I was completely in the wrong direction

Comment: Yes, the space is the "problem" in that the loop sees the two "words" separately for all the reasons listed in the links I gave.

Comment: by the way, I am facing the same problem if I have "1.txt" and "2.txt" as my files int the test_folder. I am reading the links you have provided but I am not sure if this is also happening because of the same reason or due to something else

Comment: If the files in your folder are literally `1.txt` and `2.txt` then the loop in the post should work just fine. (Add `echo "$variable"` to the loop to see what each loop is operating over.) That still doesn't make that sort of loop a good idea though.

Comment: Ohh, it counted some temporary hidden file "1.txt~" which is actually not present

Comment: The output of `echo "$variable"` are `1.txt` , `1.txt~` and `2.txt`

Comment: Are you sure you only have 2 files then?  The 1.txt~ makes me think you are currently editing 1.txt (or have used emacs to do so in the past) and have a temp file there

Comment: Then you have three files in that directory. `1.txt~` is neither temporary nor hidden. It is likely an editors backup file and whatever graphical file manager utility you are using may hide that by default (but probably shouldn't be doing that).

Comment: All my editors are closed. I also had a doubt that it might be because of an open editor but it is not so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a shell pattern (aka glob):

```
for variable in test_folder/*; do
    # ...
done
```

You will have to adjust your code to compensate for the fact that `variable` will contain something like `test_folder/foo.txt` instead of just `foo.txt`. Luckily, that's fairly easy; one approach is to start the loop body with

```
variable=${variable#test_folder/}
```

to strip the leading directory introduced by the glob.

Comment: I am facing the same problem even if I start the loop body with `variable=${variable#test_folder/}`. I have two .txt files in the folder but the code prints 3 times.

Comment: As the comments to the question indicate, you have 3 files, even if you were only aware of two of them. One option for filtering the emacs backup(s) is to use a more specific pattern like `test_folder/*.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

Never loop over the output of `ls`! Because of [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html) files having spaces in their names will be a problem. Sure, you could set `IFS` to $`\n`, but files in UNIX can also have newlines in their names.

Use `find` instead:

```
find test_folder -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -exec echo test \;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
cd "test_folder"
for variable in *; do
#your code here
done
cd ..
```

`variable` will contain only the file names